# Mac spark-shell error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have installed apache-spark-3.2.1 on Mac using homebrew. However when I start `spark-shell`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ðŸ˜: ðŸ˜: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1646)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress(Utils.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$localCanonicalHostName$1(Utils.scala:1055)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localCanonicalHostName(Utils.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ðŸ˜: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1641)
    ... 18 more
```

Running `pyspark` also gives the error

```
Python 3.9.12 (main, Apr  5 2022, 01:53:17) 
[Clang 12.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.$anonfun$loadEnvironmentArguments$3(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.loadEnvironmentArguments(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmitArguments.<init>(SparkSubmitArguments.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2$$anon$3.<init>(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.parseArguments(SparkSubmit.scala:1026)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1043)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1052)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ð: ð: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1646)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.findLocalInetAddress(Utils.scala:1005)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress$lzycompute(Utils.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localIpAddress(Utils.scala:998)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$localCanonicalHostName$1(Utils.scala:1055)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.localCanonicalHostName(Utils.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<init>(package.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.config.package$.<clinit>(package.scala)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ð: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.base/java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
    at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1641)
    ... 18 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 35, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/pyspark/context.py", line 339, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 108, in launch_gateway
    raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

I checked for the required jdk for this specific version of apache-spark using the command **brew info apache-spark**:

```
apache-spark: stable 3.2.1 (bottled), HEAD
Engine for large-scale data processing
https://spark.apache.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1 (1,472 files, 322MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-05-28 at 16:39:02
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/apache-spark.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Required: openjdk@11 ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 4,418 (30 days), 13,726 (90 days), 54,654 (365 days)
install-on-request: 4,413 (30 days), 13,708 (90 days), 54,564 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

The `java -version` of my mac outputs:

```
openjdk 11.0.15 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0, mixed mode)
```

My Path variables are:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.15/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1
export PATH="$SPARK_HOME/bin/:$PATH"
```

I also realized that, while `apache-spark` depended on `openjdk@11`, scala depends on `openjdk 18.0.1` as indicated below:

```
JVM-based programming language
https://www.scala-lang.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/scala/2.13.8 (42 files, 24.1MB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2022-05-28 at 17:03:57
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/scala.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Dependencies
Required: openjdk ✔
==> Caveats
To use with IntelliJ, set the Scala home to:
  /usr/local/opt/scala/idea
==> Analytics
install: 5,822 (30 days), 19,930 (90 days), 96,922 (365 days)
install-on-request: 5,819 (30 days), 19,897 (90 days), 96,684 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

What am I missing? All answers on stackoverflow talk about using either jdk8 or jdk11...I've tried both and still face the same error.

**Edited**
My host file is as follows:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   lols-MBP
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1       lols-MacBook-Pro.local
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost

# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Comment: did you see this? `nodename nor servname provided, or not known` seems like a useful clue

Comment: I am completely new to java and its ecosystem. Can you please give me some pointers here?

Comment: Does your computer's hostname include some characters like `ð`?

Comment: No,it doesn't. I have edited the question to include the content of my `/etc/host`

Comment: @theSekyi I think adding `127.0.0.1 <YOUR-HOSTNAME>` into `/private/etc/hosts` should solve your issue. (Based on [this guide](https://crunchify.com/getting-java-net-unknownhostexception-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-error-on-mac-os-x-update-your-privateetchosts-file/))

Comment: I did and that's what is represented as `127.0.0.1       lols-MacBook-Pro.local` in the code above but I still get the error.

Comment: Could you try disabling IPv6 for the installation, see e.g. [here](https://streambench.wordpress.com/2017/10/24/week-1-starting-with-apache-spark-streaming/). I think I saw something that connected to IPv6, but now that I'm trying I don't see it anymore... weird.

Comment: @theSekyi well you said that's your `/etc/hosts`, what I said was `/private/etc/hosts`

Comment: @AminMal, the content is same as the one I posted above.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes are you referring to `::1             localhost`?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I created `/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/conf/spark-env.sh` and added `export SPARK_DAEMON_JAVA_OPTS=”-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true”`. I then quit the terminal and restarted it but I still get the same error when I run `spark-shell`

Comment: Just though that if IPv4 doesn't work... But I see a tutorial that also requests you to perform `dscacheutil -flushcache`, [source](https://crunchify.com/getting-java-net-unknownhostexception-nodename-nor-servname-provided-or-not-known-error-on-mac-os-x-update-your-privateetchosts-file/)...

Comment: I already followed that tutorial to no avail @MaartenBodewes

Comment: The one thing I can think of is that maybe the configuration file is saved as UTF-16 or something similar, instead of ASCII / UTF-8. Maybe try and see what the encoding is of your host files. That character ð has code 0xF0... Sometimes weird character codes are also imported when copy / pasting....

Comment: `/private/etc/hosts: text/plain; charset=us-ascii` this is the file type. I also observe that even after I delete all the lines in the `/private/etc/hosts` file, I still get the same error.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes even when I comment out the entire `/private/etc/hosts` and restart the laptop, I get the same error.

Comment: It turns out that I set my hostname to an emoji. Setting it back using this command `sudo scutil --set HostName <new host name>` fixed it.